# How to use Oracle Connect by nocycle

Tags: oracle

How to use oracle connect by nocycle in sql (oracle)?

```
where connect_by_iscycle = 1 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE (prior cowner, prior ctable) = ANY (powner, ptable);
```

Above condition gives me an error, **ORA-00904 'NOCYCLE' invalid identifier**

And if I comment 'CONNECT BY NOCYCLE' line, I get error:
**ORA-00904 'connect_by_iscycle' invalid identifier**

Answer (score 0):

What version of Oracle? I seem to recall the CONNECT BY was released in one version and NOCYCLE etc. was released in a later version. I've found one reference stating the NOCYCLE is not available in 9i even though CONNECT BY is

Comment: Ah! it is 9i. Any alternatives?

Comment: Hi, not that I know of, I would only be googling it. I'm sure you'll find some egghead has foundsome way to do it!! Good luck!